# Headers goes missing on conversion of .csv file to .xls using unoconv

Tags: php, excel, csv, libreoffice, unoconv

On converting a .csv file to .xls file using unoconv, columns goes missing after IV column in xls file.
I am using shell_exec to execute the command in the PHP code like --

```
shell_exec('sudo unoconv -f xls test.csv --output=test.xls')
```

test.csv contains columns Upto AMJ but test.xls contains columns only upto IV.

How can I convert a large csv file successfully using unoconv?

Comment: With any unoconv conversion issues, the first thing to test is to try to do the conversion with plain LibreOffice. If that has the same problem, it's not an unoconv issue.